# Handling Constraints for Nonexistent Routes Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to return a 404 error when certain urls are called in my application.

In my routes.rb, i have the following

```
resources :motor_insurance_products, path: '/car-insurance' do
  collection do
    get '/:id' => 'motor_insurance_products#show'
  end
end
```

Which means that this is a valid url

```
localhost:3000/car-insurance/product-one
```

But when a user tries a web cache deception attack and uses this url

> localhost:3000/car-insurance/product-one?field=abc/text.jpg

This also passes and shows the correct page.

I want when someone puts in an invalid url like this. I would like to redirect and show error code 404 page not found. How do i do it the cleanest way in ruby?

Comment: You want the page to 404, if any query `params` are present? That doesn't make much sense. It sounds like what you should really be doing is changing to cacheing strategy to ignore params.

Comment: @TomLord how do i achieve the caching strategy to ignore params. And if i want o add a constraints that it should return 404 if the params field is there. how do i do that as well?

Comment: What is your current cacheing strategy? I cannot answer how to improve it, if I don't know what it is currently. As for returning 404 if params are present, you could do this with a `before_action` in the controller -- but it would be **weird** behaviour! It's almost certainly going to come back to bits you in future, as a bad design.

Comment: not using any current caching strategy at the moment @TomLord. Not sure why you keep saying its a bad design. im trying to prevent against web cache deception attack

Comment: So you have no cache, and are worried about someone bypassing the non-existent cache? I don't follow.

Comment: It's a bad design because a request to any given URL should (unless there's a good reason otherwise, e.g. for a search endpoint) always return the same response. `params` are by default *ignored* by the server. You never know what params might be added one day - e.g. `referrer`, or `utm_medium`, or `new_user`, or ... Literally anything. Returning a `404 ` status simply because it's an unknown parameter isn't how 99.999% of the internet works.

Comment: *"The attacker attempts to trigger the caching of content that the origin would typically not allow to be cached."* - [Benjamin Brown](https://blogs.akamai.com/2017/03/on-web-cache-deception-attacks.html) This is not something you should configure in your Rails server, but rather your caching service (CDN, load balancer, etc).